# How to use scheduling in springxd module

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-integration, spring-xd

I am working on a project which has to realize the functions below:

1. scan a folder, get the files names which are newly added
2. given a fixed time, the job will be executed as scheduled

I am currently using the spring BOOT and and the module is aimed at SpringXD

I want to use the Spring Scheduling in this module.

Thanks for giving me a description or any sources I could read. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to enable scheduling, a scheduler is needed: [link to official documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/scheduling.html)

It is really easy in fact to enable scheduling.
What you need to do, when using annotation, is to:

Add @EnableScheduling in you config class:

```
@Configuration
@EnableAsync
@EnableScheduling
public class AppConfig {
}
```

And, in a bean of your choice, just above a method add the following annotation:

```
@Scheduled(fixedDelay=5000)
```

In case you required external XML configuration:

Add the following to your xml config file

```
<task:annotation-driven executor="myExecutor" scheduler="myScheduler"/>
<task:executor id="myExecutor" pool-size="5"/>
<task:scheduler id="myScheduler" pool-size="10"/>
```

And then point out which method you want to schedule:

```
<task:scheduled-tasks scheduler="myScheduler">
    <task:scheduled ref="beanA" method="methodA" fixed-delay="5000"/>
</task:scheduled-tasks>
```

Other valid resources:
    https://spring.io/guides/gs/scheduling-tasks/
or
    http://www.mkyong.com/spring-batch/spring-batch-and-spring-taskscheduler-example/

Comment: thanks, Lore, even I am using ftp-adapter, I am not satisfied with a lot of its feathers. so what you proposed would be great help to me, I want my app more flexible.

Comment: Glad i helped, i needed that in my project too.

Answer (score 0):

I'm now using the `ftp-inbound-adapter` of `spring integration` to realise these functions.
This is for those who get here for an answer.